# Help on a coset proof

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

I want to see if I'm right, and if not, a possible solution.

**Problem Statement:** In the additive group $R^m$ of vectors, let $W$ be the set of solutions of a system of homogeneous linear equation $AX=0$. Show that the set of solutions of an inhomogeneous system $AX=B$ is either empty, or else it is an (additive) coset of W.

**My attempt at a solution:**

Either $B$ is in the set $A(R^m)$, or it is not.

If $B$ is not in the set $A(R^m)$, then there is no solution, that is the set of solutions of $Ax = B$ is empty.

Now if $B$ is in the set $A(R^m)$, then $B = Av$, for some vector $v$ in $R^m$.

I claim that the solution set for $Ax = B$, is the coset $W + v$.

Suppose $x$ is in $W + v$. then $Ax = A(w + v) = Aw + Av = 0 + B = B$,

(Since $w$ is in $W$, $Aw = 0$), so $x$ is a solution for $Ax = B$.

On the other hand, suppose $x$ is a solution for $Ax = B$.

Then $Ax - B = 0$, so $Ax - Av = 0$, so $A(x -v) = 0$,

Hence $x - v = w$, for some $w$ in $W$, thus $x = w + v$, so $x$ is in $W + v$.

Comment: Yup, it's correct.

Comment: However, you should probably change some upper case to lower case or vice-versa (e.g., $B$ in the statement is $b$ in the argument).

Comment: Ok done. Thanks.